# How to stop Gboard from trying to 'update your typing experience'?

Tags: privacy, gboard

Since a recent upgrade, Gboard started to show notifications saying "Updating your typing experience".

I have all network access of Gboard blocked with the [NetGuard firewall](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/), have all data-sharing options I could find in the Gboard settings disabled and have no permissions set for the Gboard app.

I would like to prevent it from sending and storing any data about things I entered. **Why do these notifications show and how to prevent them?**
It looks like some users reported the same problem 3 years ago on Reddit. I'm using a new Android version. The problem isn't necessarily related to the upgrade.

Comment: I'm also having the exact same issue since yesterday on my Galaxy S10e (stock Android 11 up-to-date) and Gboard (see exact version on screenshot). I've been blocking Gboard network access with NetGuard. The notifications occur several times a day.
![Gboard version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmNPM.jpg) Hope the additional info helps, and that a solution exists to stop this nonsense :)